# System cannot find the file specified while copying through CMD

Tags: c, windows, cmd

In my C program, I execute a system command to copy files from my downloads folder to a folder in desktop, the program works on .mp3 files.

The problem is that my program copies all the .mp3 files successfully from other folders except a specific folder for a reason I don't know why. I Checked the command being executed and it shows no syntax or file name errors.

The command that causes (system cannot find the file specified) error:

```
system("copy \"C:\\Users\\Mac\\Downloads\\test\\01 Andrew Bayer - Counting The Points.mp3\"
\"c:\\users\\Mac\\desktop\\AVB\"");
```

Please help me to spot the reason that causes this error in spite that the file name and path of the file is correct, and only the files in this folder(test) causes this error.

Note:
The files I'm trying to copy are downloaded from a torrent, if this may help.

Comment: Does your program have permission to access that folder?

Comment: It access all other folders except this one.

Comment: Exactly! This folder may have some special permissions!

Comment: I re-checked, System have full control of it and of its files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- Perhaps the path to your file is too long. Try to copy the folder to the root of your disk and retry the command. Or use subst to connect a drive letter to a path.
- There could be an issue with NTFS rights. Go to the security settings of the Downloads folder. Check the permissions and enable the checkbox option to replace security on all subfolders and files (remove explicitly set permissons of the child items).
- Try renaming the file to A.mp3, I'm not sure if it is possible, but the file name could contain weird unicode characters?

Comment: You're right in point no. 3. The file name contains somehow weird characters, renaming it solved the problem. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Glad to be of help! Please mark this answer so that it lists as solved.